# Passing variables to config/environments/demo.rb from the Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, runtime, metaprogramming

I have been struggling with a problem for the past days in a Ruby on Rails App I'm currently working on. I have different countries and for each country we use different Amazon S3 buckets. Amazon S3 key credentials are stored as constants in config/environments/environment_name.rb(ex:demo.rb) There is no way for me to determine which country we are operating from the config file. I can determine which country we are operating from the controllers,models,views,etc but not from the config file. Is there a Ruby meta programming or some other kind of magic that I'm not aware of so that I want to say if we are working on UK as a country in the app, use UK's bucket credentials or Germany as a country, use Germany's bucket credentials? I can't think of a way to pass parameters to environment files from the app itself. Thank you very much in advance for all your helps.

Comment: Do you have an example of how you do it in the controllers?  Is this a GeoIP thing, or are you setting some flag manually?

Comment: The reason I'm asking, is that I think what you're looking for is a middleware the sets up some additional configuration based on the request, just before rails executes.

Comment: It is not a geoip thing, I am setting everything as constants in environment files and using those credentials in controllers.

Comment: So it is based on the environment?

Comment: Yes,it is based on the environment. We have different buckets for each environment.

Comment: Answer added with a middleware example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than actually pass the configuration details to whichever S3 client you're using at launch, you should probably select the relevant credentials for each request. Your config file can define them all in a hash like so:

```
# config/s3.rb
S3_BUCKETS => { 
  :us => 'our-files-us',
  :gb => 'our-files-gb',
  :tz => 'special-case'
}
```

Then you can select the credentials on request like so (in maybe your AppController):

```
bucket_name = S3_BUCKETS[I18n.locale]
# pass this info to your S3 client
```

Make sense?

Comment: Works great, thank you very much. Just a quick question: Let's say I have a class method and I want to use associations on them. What's an easy way to do it?

Comment: sorry I just typed in something but didn't mean to ask a question but then hit enter twice and it posted it.

Comment: Great. If this worked for you then go ahead and accept it as the answer by clicking on the checkbox outline to the left of the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write a little middleware if you want to keep the knowledge of the per-country configuration out of the main application.

A middleware is extremely simple.  A do-nothing middleware looks like this:

```
class DoesNothing
  def initialize(app, *args)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

Rack powers applications through chaining a series of middlewares together... each one is given a reference to @app, which is the next link in the chain, and it must invoke `#call` on that application.  The one at the end of the chain runs the app.

So in your case, you can do some additional configuration in here.

```
class PerCountryConfiguration
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    case env["COUNTRY"]
      when "AU"
        Rails.application.config.s3_buckets = { ... }
      when "US"
        Rails.application.config.s3_buckets = { ... }
      ... etc        
    end

    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

There are several ways to use the middleware, but since it depends on access to the Rails environment, you'll want to do it from inside Rails.  Put it in your application.rb:

```
config.middleware.use PerCountryConfiguration
```

If you want to pass additional arguments to the constructor of your middleware, just list them after the class name:

```
config.middleware.use PerCountryConfiguration, :some_argument
```

You can also mount the middleware from inside of ApplicationController, which means all of the initializers and everything will have already been executed, so it may be too far along the chain.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was really helpful. I never did anything with the middleware stack before except when I used OmniAuth and Devise. I never wrote my own middleware before.

Comment: I think most people don't realise that a middleware is just a single method :)